# PostGIS difference between two tables with polygon

Tags: postgis, clip, st-intersects, st-difference

I have two polygon tables. I try to remove portions but the end result is not acceptable.
I took the time to look at different questions and answers about ST_Difference but I couldn't solve my problem.

[image]

**Table:** land

**Table:** lake (red outline)
I want to remove the lake portions in land.

the result is not perfect, there are like two segments added to my cutout. Here is the result.
[image]

**Here's the SQL request:**

```
     SELECT k.id,
       coalesce(st_difference(k.wkb_geometry,
                                 (SELECT st_union(p.wkb_geometry)
                                  FROM lake p
                                  WHERE st_intersects(k.wkb_geometry, p.wkb_geometry))), 
                                  k.wkb_geometry) AS wkb_geometry
FROM land as k;
```

Comment: Maybe the result is good, just lakes not corresponding exactly at your land polygon's borders. If you add a slight buffer to your lakes, it will remove the segments but will remove a slight interior part of the land too.

Comment: I found a great example. It meets his needs perfectly. 

Here is the reference site: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiExamplesOverlayTables

Comment: @Bak: did you achieve your desired result by buffering your Lake geometries a tiny bit as suggested ?

Comment: @Kasper: I am not getting the desired result using a buffer. 
But J. Monticolo's idea helped me a lot. I took inspiration from the link above to work around the problem.